# NoMethodError after loggin in in Ruby on Rails networking website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make an example of a small networking site, and when I log in a user, it should redirect and show his profile, but I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in User#index

Showing app/views/user/index.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `screen_name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5):

2:  Your basic information
3: 
4:

  5:
- Screen name: <%= @user.screen_name %>
  6:
- Email: <%= @user.email %>
  7:
- Password: **********
  8:

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @user object is "nil". You need to make sure that you set @user, e.g. via a "before_filter".

Comment: In my controller?

I have this two:
@user = User.new(params[:user])
and 
user = User.find_by_screen_name_and_password(@user.screen_name,@user.password)

Comment: User.new doesn't create a record.  You need to use create, or pair new + save.  If the record doesn't exist, find_by_XXXX is going to return nil.  So, not really sure if you're really running those two back-to-back, but if so, it won't work for you.

Comment: Alright, it has been solved with a simple @user = User.find(session[:user_id]).
Nevertheless, now when I press the login button in order to log in a user, I never get redirected to the user profile. I think I'll need to spend a little more time with it, thanks a lot!